# Error displaying dropdown menu on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, navigation

Can anyone figure this one out ? been stuck with it for days now .
The `Dropdown menu` works fine in browser but kinda collapses on ipad . Please help.
Im using a media query for the browser to resize on ipad, but the media-query css isen't relating any code to the navigation, `ul or li`?

[image]

http://phil6109.keaweb.dk/standard.css (Media queries at the bottom of the css page)

Comment: Unless you add code or an URL to the code to your question others won't be able to help you.

Comment: looks like all items overlap - try `display:block;` on the `li`s